# Exchange EWS GetUserAvailability() not returns meeting from all calendar

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange EWS api to getting all meeting in a time range.
using below link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643673%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I have pass my email address in attendeeInfo. This will return me only main calendar event. I need other calendar meeting also.
How can i fetch other calendar (Sub calendar meeting). 
I have calendar-Id, But how pass it in my API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No GetUserAvailbility will only return events from the default Calendar folder, this is because it uses the FreeBusy information which is only published for the default Calendar Folder. If you want details of a secondary calendar then you will need to query that directly.

Comment: Thanks Glen, Is there any other API/method in which i can know free busy time for all the calendar/folder. Currently I am using exchange FindItems() method. But this is quite slow when i fetch bulk of meeting.

Comment: No but the reason behind that is that Freebusy isn't maintained for any calendar other then the default so your searching for something that doesn't exist. What you have in EWS is FindItem so my advice would be look at ways of making that work better for you eg optimizing the code you have eg properties,filters etc, using a local cache, maybe notifications or synchronization etc. Most likely you'll find your doing a lot of redundant queries of the same information that hasn't updated etc or maybe gets updated only once an hour or day so pre-fetching/polling etc can improve performance.